# brew install java11 error: Directory not empty

Tags: homebrew, java-11

Trying to install java11 on Mac using homebrew. I get the following error:

Versions:

- MacOS 12.5.1
- HomeBrew 3.6.15

```
$ brew install java11
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Fetching openjdk@11
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/manifests/11.0.17
Already downloaded: /Users/nhegde/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/dbe2b576c95bab6391300376bf2b11c3cd7cba975a7008a831e6c8b68b1ee70e--openjdk@11-11.0.17.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/blobs/sha256:a7dd4515b5a6c3215390a6fcf07a8809b88cca277ab1c3db190bf644eebce6fe
Already downloaded: /Users/nhegde/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/a4080d6b30cfa6067ff421dfb06d476977e3f7e65ee73c7daf0f9ba03f0d2381--openjdk@11--11.0.17.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring openjdk@11--11.0.17.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /private/tmp/d20221212-9750-tiwlq
```

I checked the directory and it indeed exists.

```
$ ls -l /private/tmp/d20221212-9750-tiwlq/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  3 myuser  wheel  96 Dec 12 13:39 openjdk@11/
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to remove manually the problematic directory with:

```
sudo rm -rf /private/tmp/d20221212-9750-tiwlq/
```

Another option is to install JDK 11 from [Eclipse Temurin](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/adoptium.temurin):

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask temurin11
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (macos Ventura 13.5, Homebrew 4.1.5-55-g3cd7290) I simply rebooted the system and the problem fixed by itself ([source](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4730#discussioncomment-6776107)). Any other attempt (`brew doctor`, `brew cleanup`, uninstalling and installing again the cask, etc) was unsuccessful.